# Cut transparent hole inside UICollectionView issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, drawrect

I'm trying to cut a hole inside UICollectionView.
It works - but for some reason it cut's the `UICollectionView`behind the content\cells. I'm trying to cut it including the content\cells.

Sample :

[image]

Code:

```
class tCollection : UICollectionView
{
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        let  holeRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 60)
        var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        var holeRectIntersection: CGRect = CGRectIntersection(holeRect, rect)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Clear)
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, holeRect)


    }
}
```

**Any suggestion how to cut a hole completeley(including the cells/subviews etc')**

Comment: cells ar eplaced on top of collectionview, so what you are trying to do has to be done on cells too

Comment: @TejaNandamuri can't i cut a hole while changing the UiCollectionView it self, regardless the cells?

Comment: as far as I know you can't. But you can place a view on top of collectionview and make a hole to it.

Comment: You can make a screenshot of the view underneath the collectionview (the collection view's superview), add it to a view change the shape of that to your desired shape, add it over the collectionview and disable the user interaction on that element (if you so desire...).